# How to handle submit for all dynamically created forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

```
<tr>
    <form role="form" class="manualImportSubmit" action="http://localhost:5000/XXX" method="post">
    <td><input name="yyy" value="FormAValue" type="hidden">TestA</td>
    <td><input name="before_year" class="form-control" placeholder="Before year"/></td>
    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-mid">Submit</button></td>
    </form>
</tr>
<tr>
    <form role="form" class="manualImportSubmit" action="http://localhost:5000/XXX" method="post">
    <td><input name="yyy" value="FormbValue" type="hidden">TestB</td>
    <td><input name="before_year" class="form-control" placeholder="Before year"/></td>
    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-mid">Submit</button></td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var frm = $('.manualImportSubmit');
frm.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(frm.serialize());
    // $.ajax({
    //     type: frm.attr('method'),
    //     url: frm.attr('action'),
    //     data: frm.serialize(),
    //     success: function (data) {
    //         console.log('Submission was successful.');
    //     },
    //     error: function (data) {
    //         console.log('An error occurred.');
    //     }
    // });
});
</script>
```

So, I will be dynamically creating forms in a table (each row is it's own form).  The issue I am having is creating one function in javascript to handle all of these.  Above is my attempt, however this links all submit buttons to the final form in the table's data.  I know I could dynamically create a javascript handler for each row, however I really don't want to do that.  Is there anyway to accomplish what I am trying to do without dynamically creating javascript with each row?

To further add to this, the submit is the same for all (the exact javascript I posted)

Comment: For starters `<form>` can't be a direct child of `<tr>` or parent of `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

You need the each keyword.  Try this?  It did two submissions for me in a fiddle.

```
frm.each(function() {

    this.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(frm.serialize());
    });

});
```

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood me, I only want the clicked form submitted and data to be posted.  However, the issue was, the last form was always being submitted, regardless of which was clicked.

Comment: the clicked form is going to get submitted automatically without any script when you hit the submit button.  So, what's the context where the javascript is needed?

Comment: I want to prevent reloading and streamline what is getting posted, I just thought It would be easier with js

Comment: When u hit the button it'll only submit the form associated. The whole page will change though. On the other hand, If you want a behavior where you submit, get data back and only update certain HTML elements without a page refresh...that will be an Ajax call

Comment: Nothing needs to be returned from the restful api, just a post

Comment: Make your target of your submit a hidden iframe. .that way...no JavaScript required...example...sample for usage `<form id="myGiswebForm" method="post" action="https://******/saveForm.asp" target="myiframe">` and `<iframe style="display:none;" src="" name="myiframe"></iframe>`